# Spark Structred Streaming Pyspark Sink Csv Does'nt Append

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Write json to Kafka Topic and read json  from kafka topic. Actually I subscribe topic and write console line by line. But I have to sink/write file csv. But I can't. I write csv one time but doesn't append.

You can see my code bellow.

Thank you!

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0') \
                    .appName('kafka_stream_test')\
                    .getOrCreate()
ordersSchema = StructType() \
        .add("a", StringType()) \
        .add("b", StringType()) \
        .add("c", StringType()) \
        .add("d", StringType())\
        .add("e", StringType())\
        .add("f", StringType())

df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "product-views") \
    .load()\


df_query = df \
    .selectExpr("cast(value as string)") \
    .select(func.from_json(func.col("value").cast("string"),ordersSchema).alias("parsed"))\
    .select("parsed.a","parsed.b","parsed.c","parsed.d","parsed.e","parsed.f")\


df = df_query \
    .writeStream \
    .format("csv")\
    .trigger(processingTime = "5 seconds")\
    .option("path", "/var/kafka_stream_test_out/")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/kafka_stream_test_out/chk") \
    .start()

df.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Why do you want to append to the same file anyway? Almost all Hadoop processes are able to read whole directories, and that's how their meant to be used. Therefore Spark defaults to write multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you need this extra option `.option("format", "append")` :

```
aa = df_query \
    .writeStream \
    .format("csv")\
    .option("format", "append")\
    .trigger(processingTime = "5 seconds")\
    .option("path", "/var/kafka_stream_test_out/")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/kafka_stream_test_out/chk") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added extra option as you said. But ı have same problem. 

hdfs dfs -ls /var/kafka_stream_test_out
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - supergroup   supergroup          0 2020-01-11 15:40 /var/kafka_stream_test_out/_spark_metadata
-rw-r--r--   1 supergroup      supergroup       1460 2020-01-11 15:40 /var/kafka_stream_test_out/part-00000-2114b4f5-e045-457f-bc3c-fb4d980fdc73-c000.csv

It created csv just one time, but ıt doesn't append.

Comment: @Serkanşengönül is the error the same? Can you attached the error log message (not all the trace, only the message).

Comment: ERROR FileFormatWriter:91 - Aborting job null.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /var/kafka_stream_test_out/_spark_metadata/0 doesn't exist when compacting batch 9 (compactInterval: 10)


 ERROR MicroBatchExecution:91 - Query [id = 64d3a402-a1d7-46e3-a5b9-a5b56c8f2d2e, runId = 7f54c013-0ece-4a7e-8ddb-ebc6658f56de] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

Comment: @Serkanşengönül have you tried to delete the directory with the files and try again ? Because, the export directory with the csvs have metadata, and maybe you have metadata before append option. Try it and tell me

Comment: Yes it's works. I change the check point location user to var directory. Thank you very much.